# 3D matrix multiplication in opencv for RGB color mixing

Tags: opencv, matrix

I'm trying to perform an RGB Color mixing operation in opencv. I have the image contained in an MxNx3 Mat. I would like to multiple this with a 3x3 matrix. In Matlab I do the following:
*Flatten the image from MxNx3 to a MNx3
*multiply the MNx3 matrix by the 3x3 color mixing matrix 
*reshape back to a MxNx3

In Opencv I would like to do the following:

```
void RGBMixing::mixColors(Mat &imData, Mat &rgbMixData)
{
   float rgbmix[] = {1.4237, -0.12364, -0.30003, -0.65221, 2.1936, -0.54141, -0.38854, -0.47458, 1.8631};
   Mat rgbMixMat(3, 3, CV_32F, rgbmix);
   // Scale the coefficents
   multiply(rgbMixMat, 1, rgbMixMat, 256);
   Mat temp = imData.reshape(0, 1);
   temp = temp.t();
   multiply(temp, rgbMixMat, rgbMixData);
}
```

This compiles but generates an exception:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is
>   neither 'a rray op array' (where arrays have the same size and the
>   same number of channels) , nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op
>   array') in arithm_op, file C:/slave/WinI
>   nstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1253
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what(): 
>   C:/slave/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:
>   1253: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where
>   arrays have  the same size and the same number of channels), nor
>   'array op scalar', nor 'sca lar op array' in function arithm_op
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

---

Update 1:

This is code that appears to work:

```
void RGBMixing::mixColors(Mat &imData, Mat&rgbMixData)
{
    Size tempSize;
    uint32_t channels;

    float rgbmix[] = {1.4237, -0.12364, -0.30003, -0.65221, 2.1936, -0.54141, -0.38854, -0.47458, 1.8631};
    Mat rgbMixMat(3, 3, CV_32F, rgbmix);
    Mat flatImage = imData.reshape(1, 3);
    tempSize = flatImage.size();
    channels = flatImage.channels();
    cout << "temp channels: " << channels << " Size: " << tempSize.width << " x " << tempSize.height << endl;
    Mat flatFloatImage;
    flatImage.convertTo(flatFloatImage, CV_32F);
    Mat mixedImage = flatFloatImage.t() * rgbMixMat;
    mixedImage = mixedImage.t();
    rgbMixData = mixedImage.reshape(3, 1944);
    channels = rgbMixData.channels();
    tempSize = rgbMixData.size();
    cout << "temp channels: " << channels << " Size: " << tempSize.width << " x " << tempSize.height << endl;
}
```

But the resulting image is distorted. If I skip the multiplication of the two matrices and just assign

```
mixedImage = flatFloatImage
```

The resulting image looks fine (just not color mixed). So I must be doing something wrong, but am getting close.

Comment: Is that all the code? I don't see any initialization for `imData`.

Comment: I updated it, this code is part of several classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple of things here:

1. For scaling the coefficients, OpenCV supports multiplication by scalar so instead of `multiply(rgbMixMat, 1, rgbMixMat, 256);` you should do directly `rgbMixMat = 256 * rgbMixMat;`.
2. If that is all your code, you don't properly initialize or assign values to `imData`, so the line `Mat temp = imData.reshape(0, 1);` is probably going to crash.
3. Assuming that `imData` is a MxNx3 (3-channel Mat), you want to reshape that into a MNx3 (1-channel). According to the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#cv-reshape), when you write `Mat temp = imData.reshape(0, 1);` you are saying that you want the number of channels to remain the same, and the row, should be 1. Instead, it should be:

   `Mat myData = Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_32FC3); // 100x100x3 matrix`

   `Mat myDataReshaped = myData.reshape(1, myData.rows*myData.cols); // 10000x3 matrix`
4. Why do you take the transpose `temp = temp.t();` ?
5. When you write `multiply(temp, rgbMixMat, mixData);`, this is the [per-element product](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-multiply). You want the matrix product, so you just have to do `mixData = myDataReshaped * rgbMixMat;` (and then reshape that).

**Edit:** It crashes if you don't use the transpose, because you do `imData.reshape(1, 3);` instead of `imData.reshape(1, imData.rows);`

Try

```
void RGBMixing::mixColors(Mat &imData, Mat&rgbMixData)
{
    Size tempSize;
    uint32_t channels;

    float rgbmix[] = {1.4237, -0.12364, -0.30003, -0.65221, 2.1936, -0.54141, -0.38854, -0.47458, 1.8631};
    Mat rgbMixMat(3, 3, CV_32F, rgbmix);

    Mat flatImage = imData.reshape(1, imData.rows*imData.cols);
    Mat flatFloatImage;
    flatImage.convertTo(flatFloatImage, CV_32F);

    Mat mixedImage = flatFloatImage * rgbMixMat;

    rgbMixData = mixedImage.reshape(3, imData.rows); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, when you do the reshape, why do you do rows * cols? In the documentation it lists this field as the number of rows you want to reshape to.

Comment: If I don't do the transpose I get an run time exception.

Comment: Here is the exception I get when I don't do the transpose: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in gemm, file C:/slave/WinI
nstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 718
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:/slave/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:
718: error: (-215) a_size.width == len in function gemm


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: @user1712316 You do rows * cols because you want to go from `rows x cols x 3` to `(rows*cols) x 3`. This is what you happens when you say "flatten MxNx3 to a MNx3".